# how can type text in the ajax combo box

Tags: asp.net

i added ajax combo box to my page, but i have 2 problems.

1- i can not type in that.

2- when i type in that , it automatically find matched words.
for example when i type "j" , it finds "jack".

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs"  Inherits="_Default" %>

<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="asp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Untitled Page</title>
    </head>
   <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

    <asp:ComboBox ID="ComboBox1" runat="server" AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend" 
            DropDownStyle="DropDownList" 

              style="display: inline;">
        <asp:ListItem>masoud</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>jack</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:ComboBox>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Is your browser Firefox? If so, you may have to change the MaxLength property of the ComboBox control to a value other than the default 0.

Answer (score 0):

This link will show you how to use all of the ajax controls, look at the combo box one. And you can see which one you need then.

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/ComboBox/ComboBox.aspx

That is a link to all of the ajax controls with samples.

Comment: If you set the "Dropdownsyle" property in the aspx page to DropDown, that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

as @CallumHolden said.. if you will set the dropdownstyle property to dropdown rather than dropdownlist it will work. this solved my problem as well.