# Not able to type in Combo box in asp.net Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am not able to type in Combo box in asp.net. Below is my code

```
 <cc1:ComboBox ID="ddlCustomerName" 
      OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCustomerName_SelectedIndexChanged" 
      AutoPostBack="True"  
      AutoCompleteMode="SuggestAppend" 
      DropDownStyle="Simple" CaseSensitive="False" 
      ItemInsertLocation="Append" Width="550px" Height="26px" 
      AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server">
</cc1:ComboBox>
```

This is how I am binding the list.

```
private void FillCustomerName()
    {
        SqlParameter[] spa = new SqlParameter[1];
        spa[0] = new SqlParameter("@Type", 3);
        DataSet ds = gs.Sp_SELECT("Sp_Dropdown_Customer", spa);
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            ddlCustomerName.DataTextField = "CompanyName";
            ddlCustomerName.DataValueField = "UserId";
            ddlCustomerName.DataSource = ds;
            ddlCustomerName.DataBind();
            ddlCustomerName.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select", "-1"));
            ddlCustomerName.SelectedIndex = -1;
            ddlCustomerName.AppendDataBoundItems = false;
        }
    }
```

I have tried answer provided over [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15041485/how-can-type-text-in-the-ajax-combo-box) but no luck. I have used exact same code for website which is working fine but same code for Web Application is not working.

Comment: Refer- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805638/making-a-combo-box-editable

Comment: @Priya not working

Comment: The answer that you provided is for `Ajax.ComboBox` not for regular  `ComboBox`.

Comment: @SeM Yes it is. I have added `AjaxControlToolkit` too

Answer (score 0):

Use Property **AutoCompleteSource="ListItems"**  and **DropDownStyle="DropDown"** instead of DropDownStyle="Simple" in order to type and get suggested item form combox.

Comment: `AutoCompleteSource` property is for Windows Form and I am having web Form